# Can a local variable be used out of a method?

Tags: java, local-variables

I've got stuck in a problem about local variables.

The following is not my original code but I use a simple example to present my question:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner userScan=new Scanner(System.in);    
    do{
        int input1=userScan.nextInt();
    }while(input1>10);
}
```

My purpose is to let a user type in an integer which is in my intended range.
If the typed number does not meet the rule, I hope the user can type again until it does. However, the "input1" is a local variable, so it will not be valid in the expression of while. But I do not want the user to re-type the integer again. Using only one variable would be better. Does anyone have advices about it or other ways which can implement this idea?
Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean by retype the integer again

Comment: could you please reply

Comment: @javafan Sorry, I didn't describe it clearly. I mean it works if I use "while(input1=userScan.nextInt()>0)" to let user type their number again to get the result I want. Anyway, the following answers work for me. Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
        Scanner userScan=new Scanner(System.in);    
        int input1;
        do{
            input1=userScan.nextInt();
        }while(input1>10);
    }
```

just declare input1 outside of the scope of do while loop

Comment: No need for the `= 0` on `int input1 = 0;` The variable will be definitely assigned before it's tested.

Comment: it's just the same anyway I always get that error so just always initialized a loop control variable

Comment: sorry I didn't see the userScan object Mr. T.J Crowder is right I was focusing on do-while loop scope I thought it was just a loop control variable

Comment: It works. I always declared a variable and initialize it at the same time, so I forgot that I can separate them and move the declaration out of the loop. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do this? :D
Delcare the input1 outside the do...while loop, then it can be used in while statement.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner userScan=new Scanner(System.in);  
        int input1 = 0;
        do{
            input1=userScan.nextInt();
        }while(input1>10);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `input1` variable scope i.e., the scope of your `input1` variable is limited to `do` `while` block (i.e., `{ }` code), so just declare the variable outside the loop.

```
int input1 = 0;//scope is now wider, not just limited to the loop
do {
   input1=userScan.nextInt();
} while(input1>10);
```